# Tensorflow RNN cells weight sharing

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am wondering if in the following code the weights of the two stacked cells are shared:

```
cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_dim)
stacked_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * 2)
```

If they are not shared, how to force sharing in any RNNs?

Note: 
I might more probably want to share weights in a nested input-to-output connected RNN configuration where the first layer is cloned many times for every input of the second layer (e.g. sentences where 1st layer represents letters and 2nd layer represents words gathered from iterating 1st layer's outputs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see that the weights are not shared by executing the following script:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("scope1") as vs:
  cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(10)
  stacked_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * 2)
  stacked_cell(tf.Variable(np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.float32), name="moo"), tf.Variable(np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.float32), "bla"))
  # Retrieve just the LSTM variables.
  vars = [v.name for v in tf.all_variables()
                    if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]
  print vars
```

You will see that besides dummy variables it returns two sets of GRU weights: those with "Cell1" and those with "Cell0".

To make them shared, you can implement your own cell class that inherits from `GRUCell` and always reuses the weights by the means of always using the same variable scope:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class SharedGRUCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell):
    def __init__(self, num_units, input_size=None, activation=tf.nn.tanh):
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell.__init__(self, num_units, input_size, activation)
        self.my_scope = None

    def __call__(self, a, b):
        if self.my_scope == None:
            self.my_scope = tf.get_variable_scope()
        else:
            self.my_scope.reuse_variables()
        return tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell.__call__(self, a, b, self.my_scope)

with tf.variable_scope("scope2") as vs:
  cell = SharedGRUCell(10)
  stacked_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * 2)
  stacked_cell(tf.Variable(np.zeros((20, 10), dtype=np.float32), name="moo"), tf.Variable(np.zeros((20, 10), dtype=np.float32), "bla"))
  # Retrieve just the LSTM variables.
  vars = [v.name for v in tf.all_variables()
                    if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]
  print vars
```

This way the variables between the two GRUCells are shared. Note that you need to be careful with shapes, since the same cell need to work with both the raw input and the output of itself.